# Something's not right with this Timing

Tags: javascript

This views "`est! T`" when run. That tells me that the timing's wrong.
I'm going for a Scrolling Message that says `Test!`, moving every half-second.

```
scroll()

function scroll() {
settext("Test! ")
wait(500)
settext(" Test!")
wait(500)
settext("! Test")
wait(500)
settext("t! Tes")
wait(500)
settext("st! Te")
wait(500)
settext("est! T")
wait(500)
}

function wait(a) {
self.setInterval(nothing,a)
}

function nothing() {}

function settext(text) {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't *wait* in a JavaScript function.  That's not how it works.

When you use `setTimeout` (or `setInterval`), what's happening is... you are telling JavaScript to run the passed function *in* a certain number of milliseconds (or to run it once *every* X milliseconds).  It doesn't run the passed function there, it pushes onto the event queue.

What this code is doing is calling `settext()` to change the `innerHTML`, then calling `wait()` to add (another) interval to the event queue.

Every 500ms, the `nothing` function will fire (this will happen 6 times... every 500ms).

If you want the text to appear for 500ms and then change, you'll have to call `settext` *inside* the `setTimeout`.  For example:

```
settext("Test! ");

setTimeout(function(){
    settext(" Test!");
}, 500);
```

As you can see, this might get a bit messy with all of your `settext` calls.  One thing you can do is use an array to hold all the possible states, then use *one* `setInterval` call to cycle through them.

```
function scroll() {
    var states = ["Test! ", " Test!", "! Test", "t! Tes", "st! Te", "est! T"],
        currState = 0;

    settext("Test! ");
    currState++;

    setInterval(function(){
        settext(states[currState]);
        currState++;

        if(currState === states.length){
            currState = 0;
        }
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: Oh, I thought `setinterval` meant "Repeat this task until [x] ms. pass", not "Repeat this task every [x] ms. indefinitly"

Comment: @user5428858: I'm glad I could clear up the confusion, then :-)